# Need help identifying a decorative font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, ttf

Back in the 90s I used a small utility called "Bannermania" from Broderbund Software to make banners. It came with several fonts in a proprietary binary format and I need a TTF version of one of them called "Hollywood":

[image: Hollywood font]

I've tried WhatTheFont! and fontspring.com without luck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Banner Mania! I'm dating myself with admitting that this post gave me all kinds of nostalgia vibes! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Harlow Solid](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/harlow/) from myfonts.com is the base although in your example it seems thinner and less inclined, there are more coincidences than differences.

[image: harlow]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!